# Multiple transforms using Compass

Tags: css, sass, transform, compass-sass

I'm in the case where I have multiple transforms on one element, so my question is how do you translate this into Compass while keeping the named transforms:

> -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%) scale(0.5); 
>   -moz-transform: translateY(-100%) scale(0.5);
>   transform: translateY(-100%)
>   scale(0.5);
>   -ms-transform: translateY(-100%) scale(0.5);

Something like : `@include translateY(-100%) scale(0.5);`

Thank you.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to use the `transform` mixin rather than the shortcut mixins for each specific transformation:

```
@include transform(translateY(-100%) scale(0.5));
```

It's pretty simple - just pass it the transforms you want, using the official css syntax.

Comment: Yep, that's it, completely missed it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just pointing out that the parameters are a space-separated list, not comma-separated (I didn't notice that at first)